# A Simple pthread_create causing 100% CPU usage in Qt

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, pthreads

When a simple Thread is run with just an infinite loop in it causing 100% CPU, how come is this possible?

My thread call is as follows on a QEvent in Qt dialog class, Say on a button click.

```
  pthread_t thread_id;
  pthread_create( &thread_id, NULL, DataCollectionThread, (void*) this );
```

And my thread procedure is,

```
void* DataCollectionThread( void* pParam )
{
   ((m_DataCollection*)pParam)->m_ReadDatafromport();
   return NULL;
}
```

And this `ReadData()` contains...

```
while(1)
{
}
```

My requirement is collecting data from serial port and plot a graph continuously. But as the CPU usage is 100%, any hardware interrupt in between plotting cause the plotting to stall, as the `CPU` switches the task to handle interrupt.

I am calling this thread in a `Qt::Dialog` based class. I am pretty sure that nothing other than this is triggered. What's wrong with this? Does a simple infinite loop causes 100% CPU consumption eh? Or Is there any problem with using pthread_create in Qt?

**EDIT**:For Jonathon Reinhart

This is the actual while loop

```
while( 1 )
    {

            while(( Dataisavailable))
            {
                 //push the read data to stack
            }



        if(!m_DataReadable)
            break;
      }
```

Comment: while(1) == 100% single core cpu load

Comment: "*But as the CPU usage is 100%, any hardware interrupt in between plotting cause the plotting to stall, as the CPU switches the task to handle interrupt.*"  This seems a rather dubious explanation to me.  What are you actually seeing?  Stuttering?  Plotting just completely stops?  In actual fact, I suspect that what's really causing any problem you see is the fact that you're thrashing the mutex behind `LockLeadData()` pretty badly.

Comment: Well by stall I mean,For example when I connect a usb while plotting, the plotting just stall for a few seconds while automounting usb,  and come back to normal after that+ after plotting some noise.ie, stall for a few seconds,  plot of noise values for a few seconds,  and then plot of normal values. The thing that most amazes me is the noise value I am getting. Does this USB inclusion introduces any noise in serial device? And above all the processor in my development kit is only of 1 Ghz single core:(, to add further complexity.

Comment: @Managu, Do you have any guess on this noise issue?

Comment: I don't think you've presented enough information for me to comment on your noise issue.  Things like "what are you actually trying to graph", "how is your input being converted to data in your program", maybe "what actual hardware is involved", etc.  Moreover, addressing such an issue would probably be best done in a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple hack to get around this:  Go to sleep for (short) periods to let the CPU do other stuff.  `#include <ctime>` and add somewhere in your loop:

```
struct timespec ts;
ts.tv_sec=0;
ts.tv_nsec=10000000; // 10 milliseconds
nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
```

Of course, it would be better if you could explicitly sleep until you have actual work to do (more input to read, a full queue to trim).  But adding in short sleeps will probably be sufficient.

It might make sense to look into your `m_pDataProvider` object's implementation.  Check for or add a method allowing you to sleep until there's more data.  If you're just reading from a character device (e.g. ttyS0), `poll` or `select` might be useful here.

Comment: I thought this solved the problem. Using sleep ofcourse lowered CPU usage considerably. But  It doesn't allow other events [for example a button click] To be processed while the paintevent is running! it just get scheduled to end, And is only executed after paintevent end.wth? without sleep fucntion all events were getting processed while paintevent is active.

Comment: Errm, right: No GUI interaction will be processed while you're handling a paintEvent.  Structure your code so that you don't spend a lot of time in paintEvent

Comment: Maybe, for example, by having `paintEvent` just draw the grap once, overriding `timerEvent` with a function which calls `update()`, and then invoking `setTimer(10)` in the widget's constructor.  That is, periodically redraw the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike [cooperative multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-operative_multitasking#Cooperative_multitasking.2Ftime-sharing), true OS-supported threads allow the CPU to interrupt code that's locked like this.  So your computer isn't *completely* dying.  But some degradation will occur.  The computer doesn't have a good way of knowing not to try its best to run the code it's given if there is work to do...short of scheduling tools like [nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29)

Sometimes you can mitigate the problems caused by something like this with "thread priorities".  Qt has a [QThread::setPriority()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qthread.html#setPriority) abstraction but note that it says:

> The effect of the priority parameter is dependent on the operating system's scheduling policy. In particular, the priority will be ignored on systems that do not support thread priorities (such as on Linux, see http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler for more details).

Seems the Qt people looked at thread priorities under linux and [gave up](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2007-05/thread00746-0.html).  So if that's your platform, then you likely should just design your system so it doesn't spin like this.

I'd be curious what happened if you change `ReadData()` to...

```
QMutex dummy;
while(1)
{
    QMutexLocker locker (&dummy);
}
```

(which was my way of trying something that may be more effectively done with the `sched_yield` that @jweyrich just mentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

YES.

```
while(1) { }
```

Is going to do the following:

```
1. Does the number 1 equate to true?
2. Yes.
3. Go to 1.
```

The CPU is going to continuously do this whenever that thread is executing. Why are you starting a thread just to put it in a spin loop that does nothing?

Comment: I didn't know that this loop causes 100% CPU. Actually there is code for collecting data from serial port and also I am breaking the loop after plotting for a while with the help of flag. But as long as cpu is in this while loop, it is consuming 100% CPU.

Comment: It is rarely correct for user code to spin waiting on a flag. It is just burning CPU for no reason.

Comment: I have added the exact code in while loop. Check my question again!

Comment: @spyke: Your loop is keeping the processor busy whenever your thread gets a timeslice to execute. You may fix this by calling `sched_yield()` at the end of your loop. This will yield the processor, and give chance for other threads/processes to run, making your loop not consume all the power. You can read more about [scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) if your wish.

Comment: You'll still see 100% CPU usage if you `sched_yield()`, though other threads may become more responsive.

Comment: @Managu only if the other threads/processes are as CPU-bound as this one currently is.

Comment: @jweyrich: `sched_yield()` allows other threads to run if any of them wish to.  But if no other threads wish to run, the yielding thread will be scheduled to run again immediately.  Thus adding a `sched_yield()` to a busy loop will still result in (essentially) 100% CPU load.  Or if you like, 0% CPU time spent idle.

Comment: @Managu: which would be okay if no other thread/process needs to run. After all, that's what any sane scheduler should do. An alternative to this would be to sleep/usleep/nanosleep/whatever, effectively giving up on the current timeslice, and possibly many others, depending on how much time you specify. Yet, the proper solution does vary according to each scenario.

Comment: @jweyrich: No argument, then.  BTW, you definitely want `nanosleep`.  `usleep` and `sleep` are usually implemented by means of signals (namely SIGALRM), and signals and threads tend to interact poorly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13138/discussion-between-managu-and-jweyrich)